# string.find not working with list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Seeing a weird issue with `string.find`.

I have a following list:

```
lstofpro = ["Brown, John", "Smith,Jon"]
keywordstring = "Something: Smith,Jon Account Number: 99999"

for p in lstofpro:
    if keywordstring.find(p.strip()) != -1:
        print ("Found a match for : %s" % p)
```

The above doesn't find a successful match even if the value exists in the `keyworstring`. If I change `p.strip()` to hard coded value of "Smith,Jon" it successfully finds it.

Guys have any clue what could be wrong?

Comment: It's working on my machine. Are you sure your indentations are correct?

Comment: works fine with python 2.7.3.  Please do python -V and say EXACTLY what version of python you are using.

Comment: Question is tagged with Python 3. Works fine in both 3.2 and 3.3. And the code is not complex enough to contain anything that has changed in any recent (or less recent) version. It’s using very basic features, and Py3-safe syntax (print function).

Comment: PS, you're not calling `string.find` (a function in the `string` module, which doesn't exist anymore in 3.x), but `str.find` (a method of the `str` class).

Comment: There appears to be a problem with the way I am populating lstofpro. In the code above it is hardcoded but actually it is getting populated with cur.execute("select * from table")
    lstofpro = [x for x, in cur]

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you can't use the "in" operator? I tried your algorithm with it like this and got the desired results:

```
lstofpro = ["Brown, John", "Smith,Jon"]
keywordstring = "Something: Smith,Jon Account Number: 99999"

for p in lstofpro:
   if p in keywordstring:
      print ("Found a match for : %s" % p)
```

Comment: That works, and it's better code than the OP's—but the OP's code already works too (as written), so it doesn't really solve any problem. I think this would be better as a comment.